# Nueva librerías de androidx

Tags: android

Se me ha actualizado Android Studio y he empezado una nueva app y me surge el problema que en los XML todo se sobrepone. Lo he intentado poniendo en el padre  android:orientation="vertical" y también poniendo en los hijos android:layout_below="@id_el que debe de estar por encima" (aunque este me dice que esta desactualizado). Pero nada de nada no funciona, sigue sobrepuesto.

Parece ser que android:orientation="vertical" ya no funciona os pongo lo que he puesto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".bbb.BlankFragmentbbb">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sss"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sss"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="bbbbbb"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

```
</FrameLayout>
```

Alguna idea.

Comment: OK. Pero es el XML de un Fragment, si lo le pongo <FrameLayout> no funcionara correctamente el fragment. ¿Es esto asi?

Comment: Estas seguro que ese es el layout que estas usando? no deberias tener problemas @FernandoDelgadoFernandez

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando de manera incorrecta el [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout), aquí un poco de la explicación de acuerdo a la documentación oficial:

> Generalmente el FrameLayout debe de ser usado para contener una sola vista hija, porque puede ser difícil organizar vistas hijas sin que se estas se sobrepongan una sobre otra.

Te recomiendo que cambies el layout, existen diferentes tipos que puedes utilizar para organizar tu vista de la manera que requieres, por ejemplo usando [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) tu vista quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sss"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="bbbbbb"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```